# Using tcolorbox for a sidebar

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox

I'm trying to re-write a sidebar environment I have that is based on `wrapfigure` and such into something based on `tcolorbox`. However, I've run into a couple of issues.

For reference, here is my old environment:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment*{sidebar}[3][0.5\textwidth]
{
    % less vertical margin around wrapfigures
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
    \colorlet{savedcolor}{inline code}
    \colorlet{inline code}{inline code inverted}
    \renewcommand{\dummy}{#1}
    \wrapfigure{#2}{#1}
        \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#3}
        \renewcommand{\@currentlabelname}{#3}
        \phantomsection
        \rule{#1}{1pt}

        \rule{#1}{18pt}

        \vspace{-18pt}
        \centerline{\textcolor{white}{#3}}

        \vspace{5pt}
        \footnotesize
        \leftskip=5pt
        \rightskip=5pt
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        % restore the inline code color for the body of the bar
        \colorlet{inline code}{savedcolor}
}
{

        \leftskip=0pt
        \rightskip=0pt
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \rule{\dummy}{1pt}
        \rule[.19in]{\dummy}{2.5pt}
    \endwrapfigure
}
\makeatother
```

It works, but it's far from pretty. That's why I'm looking to use `tcolorbox`, since I've had good success using it in other contexts.

Here's a MWE of what I have so far:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{inline code}{RGB}{194,61,53}
\definecolor{inline code inverted}{RGB}{193,153,151}

\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily\color{inline code},keywordstyle=\color{inline code},stringstyle=\color{inline code},keepspaces=true]}

\newtcolorbox{cbar}[2][]{
    parbox=false, % normal paragraph spacing
    height from=2.5cm to 100cm,
    halign=justify,
    sharp corners,
    colframe=black,
    colback=black!15!white,
    fontupper=\tiny,% font size for body of text
    title=\scriptsize \textsc{#2},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{cbar}[label=lab:testing]{Test Bar (some \code{Code})}
    Here is a test bar with some \code{Code}.

    \blindtext
\end{cbar}

Hello, \code{code}. And here is a reference to \ref{lab:testing}, which has name \nameref{lab:testing}.

\end{document}
```

And here's how it renders:

[image]

My problems are:

1. I don't know how to get references to work like they did in my prior environment. As you can see, my old environment uses `renewcommand` and `phantomsection` to assign the label text so that references to a sidebar would just print out the sidebar's title (using `nameref`). I have no idea how to achieve the same with `newtcolorbox`.
2. Similarly, I previously used `colorlet` to override the color for inline code output by the `code` command. I suspect this is a variation on question 1, but I'm not sure where to *put* this logic now that I'm using `newtcolorbox`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I would help in order to know what referencing output you would expect from this new `tcolorbox` environment. There's no code showing what `sidebar` was supposed to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the issue with the wrong `nameref` reference use the `\nameref` key, which can be set to the title.

Since there is no counter involved, `label=` has no grip to do anything useful. Provide `auto counter` as init option of the new box definition.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{inline code}{RGB}{194,61,53}
\definecolor{inline code inverted}{RGB}{193,153,151}

\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily\color{inline code},keywordstyle=\color{inline code},stringstyle=\color{inline code},keepspaces=true]}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{cbar}[2][]{
    parbox=false, % normal paragraph spacing
    height from=2.5cm to 100cm,
    halign=justify,
    sharp corners,
    colframe=black,
    colback=black!15!white,
    fontupper=\tiny,% font size for body of text
    title={\thetcbcounter\ \scriptsize \textsc{#2}},
    nameref={\scriptsize \textsc{#2}},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{cbar}[label=lab:testing]{Test Bar (some \code{Code})}
    Here is a test bar with some \code{Code}.

    \blindtext
\end{cbar}

Hello, \code{code}. And here is a reference to \ref{lab:testing}, which has name \nameref{lab:testing}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! For question 2 I put the `\colorlet` in the `title` and it seemed to work fine (even resets it automatically instead of making me manage that). The final problem (I think) I had is that the `code` command had an explicit font size, which was too big for the sidebar. I fixed that by using `relsize` instead.